# I get AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, web

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

image_number = 0
strogram_number = 1
link = f"https://kartinki.pics/108401-haski-motocikl.html"

responce = requests.get(link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce, "lxml")
block = soup.find("div", class_ ="body")
all_images = block.find_all("div", class_ = "fotocontext")

for image in all_images:
    image_link = image.find("a").get("href")
    download_storage = requests.get(f"{link}{image_link}").text
    download_soup = BeautifulSoup(download_storage, "lxml")
    download_block = download_soup.find("div", class_ = "fulloptions").find("div", class_ = "otstupi")
    result_link = download_block.find("a").get("href")

    image_bytes = requests.get(f"{link}{result_link}").content

    with open(f"img/{image_number}.jpg", "wb") as file:
        file.write(image_bytes)
        
        image_number += 1
        print(f"Good Download {image_number}.jpg ")
```

url = https://kartinki.pics/108401-haski-motocikl.html

```
 download_block = download_soup.find("div", class_ = "fulloptions").find("div", class_ = "otstupi")
```

This code gives an error. That it's not finding the block. The rest of the code worked. I looked everywhere I could. But I couldn't find a specific code that could fix this error.

Console:

````
    download_block = download_soup.find("div", class_ = "fulloptions").find("div", class_ = "otstupi")
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'```
````

Comment: Beautifulsoup has the habit of returning `None` for pretty much everything not found. You always have to account for that. And BTW programming is not about code finding.